# How to use a character name to extract data from a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm wondering why the first version of my code below (`pred`) works OK, but the second version does not work OK?

I know the problem is with using `g <- names(fit$model)[2]` producing `"hp"` instead of `hp` in the second version. But I'm wondering how to get the second version to work OK like the first version?

```
library(rstanarm)
fit <- stan_glm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

pred <- posterior_predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(hp = 93))   # Works OK![FIRST Version]

g <- names(fit$model)[2]
pred <- posterior_predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(g = 93)) # Does not work! [SECOND Version]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the name of that data column to the value of `g`; `setNames` will do it in one line, otherwise you can make a temporary variable for the new data frame and use `names`.

```
pred <- posterior_predict(fit, newdata = setNames(data.frame(tmp = 93), g))
```

or

```
tmp <- data.frame(tmp = 93)
names(tmp) <- g
pred <- posterior_predict(fit, newdata = tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we are using the `tidyverse` way, then the string object can be made to assign (`:=`) as the column names

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(!! g := 93) %>% 
# or
# data_frame(!! g := 93) %>% 
     posterior_predict(fit, newdata = .)
```

-checking the answer with @Aaron's approach

```
set.seed(24)
pred2 <- tibble(!! g := 93) %>%
                posterior_predict(fit, newdata = .)
set.seed(24)
pred <-  posterior_predict(fit, newdata = setNames(data.frame(tmp = 93), g))
identicalpred, pred2)
#[1] TRUE
```